# CVS Ignore Directories

Tags: cvs

How do you set to ignore folders and all its subdirectories in CVS?

It's getting pretty annoying when it commits every file in my `\bin`, `\obj` or `\TestResult` folders.

Tried `*\TestResult` in the ignore list - to no avail.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

you can create a `.cvsignore` file in your directories. [See here for details](http://www.cvsnt.org/manual/html/cvsignore.html)

In your case the `.cvsignore` of your project root would look like

```
bin
obj
TestResult
```

Comment: One cvsignore file per directory?

Comment: @John Yes, one file per directory where there are files or directories  to be ignored. Of course you do not need to put them in or below ignored directories. If there are filetypes or directories which should everywhere be ignored you can add them to one of the personal, repository or system cvsignore files.

Comment: .cvsignore only seems to work for ignoring files during "commit" operations. It does not work for "update" operations, unfortunately, and AFAICT there is no way to ignore directories during "update".

Comment: @dpk I think it's caused by the fact that you already committed some files which you want to ignore... To make it work also for update, you have to remove cvs ignore, commit it, remove the files which should be ignored, commit that removal, add cvs ignore with the files which should be ignored and commit. This way you will get rid of them from cvs so they won't show up as incoming changes.

Answer (score 3):

I also had to add `.cvsignore` into the `.cvsignore` file, because

`cvs up` returned `? .cvsignore`

Note that I am using 1.12.13-MirDebian-9

Comment: I always commit .cvsignore files, because they should be used by every team member.

Comment: I guess it all depends what you are doing, if it is to affect others ... I was mixing cvs and subversion, my `.cvsignore` contained just `.svn` (this was when subversion had `.svn` dirs in every directory), I was to import stuff from cvs to subversion and kept them in parallel for some time ... just to be on the safe side ...

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the way above and it works, except a detail: **if you want to ignore a folder, and you have committed this folder to CVS server, you cannot delete this folder and `commit` to delete it in CVS repository. Eclipse will ignore your delete.** You have to:

- Move all files in this folder to another location,
- In Eclipse, `synchronize` with CVS,
- `mark as merged` to all files removed,
- they will appear with `-` before them. `commit` to delete them in CVS server.
- create `.cvsignore` file in this folder, with `New - File`, type `.cvsignore` as file name, and edit it to match patrons of file names of those you want to ignore.
- `synchronize` again, to `commit` this `.cvsignore`.
- Move files back to this folder. You are done.